# jqgrid: get and set multi level summary footer row

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

In the JQGrid below I have two levels of grouping; "Group" (highlighted) and "SubGroup".

How do I to get or set the values of the "Group" row?

This is not the footer of the grid its a group summary footer so using footerData will not work.

How do I access summary rows?

[image: Grouped JQGrid]

Comment: Could you specify more detailed what you mean under "access summary rows"? Do you need to use some custom `summaryType`? What is input information for you for specifying the group which you need to "access"? Do you familiar with parameter `groupingView` and the property `groups` of it? It's better if you include an example (JavaScript code with local data) of the grid which you use and explain what you need on the example.

Comment: can you give more specification for your question?

Comment: All I need to do is be able to access the summary group footer cells.

Comment: @Asmussen: `$("#grid").find(">body>tr.jqfoot>td")` get you *all cells* or *all summary group footer*. You can access the cells *after* there are filled of cause (so in callbacl `loadComplete` for example). Can it help you? Probably not. You need probably **identify specific cell in specific summary row**. So you have reformulate your question more clear. Moreover instead of *changing* values of summary row you can specify *custom calculation function* for the column using `summaryType` defined as function.